# Smooth panning with JavaFX

Tags: java, macos, javafx, touch, gesture

I have a MacBook Pro with a touch enabled trackpad. When I open a large image with the Mac preview app I can let the image slide softly over the screen with a two finger swipe gesture. Now I would like to do the same inside a JavaFX app (see code below). In principle this seems to work but the movement is not smooth. The image jumps in roughly 10 pixel increments which just looks ugly. I experimented with the JavaFX gestures but I did not get it to move smoothly. Can anybody tell me whether this is possible with JavaFX at all and if yes how to do that?

```
package jfxfeatures.control.scrollpane;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollCanvas1 extends Application {

    // Some large image in the order of 4000x3000 pixels.
    private final static File file = new File("some large image file here");

    ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());            
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setPannable(true);
            scrollPane.setContent(canvas);

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setPrefSize(1200, 800);
            root.setCenter(scrollPane);

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```